# PHPMailer not accepting docx mime type

Tags: php, docx, mime

using "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" to attach docx but PHPMailer gives an error. The attachment code is:

```
$maxsize = 19 * 1024 * 1024; 
$types = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword','application/zip','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); 


foreach(array_keys($_FILES['attach_file']['name']) as $key) {

   $source = $_FILES['attach_file']['tmp_name'][$key]; 
   $filename = $_FILES['attach_file']['name'][$key]; 

if(filesize($source) < $maxsize && in_array(mime_content_type($source),$types)){

$mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);

}
```

Seen a number of queries about docx issues, whats the catch?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: If you checked the `mime_content_type()` result you'd notice it probably detects it as plain zip archive.

Comment: Masoud Keshavarz: my bad about the error, it was due to a missing }. mario: it is returning inode/x-empty

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the error was due to a missing } and the reason why I was not receiving docx in the email as an attachment was due to the fact that I was testing the attachment with an empty docx file. It works fine if the file has some content and not totally empty.